# Разместить два MediaElement

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

В какой блок надо поместить два MediaElement, чтобы можно было разместить их как на картинке
[image: 1]
Одно видео должно показываться по верх другого.

Answer (score 3):

Для абсолютного позиционирования на экране есть элемент [Canvas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.aspx)

Вашу задачу можно достаточно гибко решить с помощью обычного [Grid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.aspx)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <MediaElement Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <MediaElement Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

В результате большой `MediaElement` занимает 2 колонки и две строки. Маленький же находится в левом нижнем углу.

Comment: По идее, даже колонки/строки не нужны, просто достаточно задать маленькому `MediaElement`'у жёсткий размер и `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`.

Comment: @VladD Да, Alignment вместе с margin покрывают часть сценариев. Но  без колонок нельзя, например, задать относительный размер.

Comment: Это да, ТС не сформулировал, какой лэйаут ему нужен.